# Haskell Random Generation

Tags: haskell, random

Could someone describe how the following type constructor and functions work?

```
type Rand a = State StdGen a  

getRandom :: (Random a) => Rand a
getRandom = get >>= (\r -> let (a,g) = random r in (put g) >> (return a))

runRand :: Int -> Rand a -> a
runRand n r = evalState r $ mkStdGen n

runRandIO :: Rand a -> IO a
runRandIO r = randomIO >>= (\rnd -> return $ runRand rnd r)

getRandoms :: (Random a) => Int -> Rand [a]
getRandoms n = mapM (\_ -> getRandom) [1..n]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start at the beginning:

```
type Rand a = State StdGen a
```

This line tells you that `Rand a` is a type synonym for a `State` type, whose state is given by `StdGen` and whose eventual value is of type `a`. This will be used to store the state of the random number generator between each request for a random number.

The code for `getRandom` can be converted into do notation:

```
getRandom :: (Random a) => Rand a
getRandom = do
  r <- get                   -- get the current state of the generator
  let (a,g) = random r in do -- call the function random :: StdGen -> (a, StdGen)
    put g                    -- store the new state of the generator
    return a                 -- return the random number that was generated
```

The `runRand` function takes an initial seed `n` and a value `r` of type `Rand a` (which, remember, is just a synonym for `State StdGen a`). It creates a new generator with `mkStdGen n` and feeds it to `evalState r`. The function `evalState` just evaluates the return value of a `State s a` type, ignoring the state.

Again, we can convert `runRandIO` into `do` notation:

```
runRandIO :: Rand a -> IO a
runRandIO r = do
  rnd <- randomIO        -- generate a new random number using randomIO
  return (runRand rnd r) -- use that number as the initial seed for runRand
```

Finally, `getRandoms` takes a number `n` representing the number of random values that you want to generate. It builds a list `[1..n]` and applies `getRandom` to the list. Note that the actual values in `[1..n]` aren't used (you can tell because the lambda function starts with `\_ -> ...`). The list is just there to have something with the correct number of elements. Since `getRandom` returns a monadic value, we use `mapM` to map over the list, which causes the state (i.e. `StdGen`) to be threaded correctly through each of the calls to `getRandom`.

Answer (score 5):

The basic idea is simple--to create pseudorandom numbers, you need to maintain some state between function calls. So the type `Rand a` is defined to mean "`a` along with the state needed for randomness".

The state is stored using the [`State` monad](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/State_Monad). This provides two main actions--`get` and `put`, which do exactly what they sound like. So `getRandom` just looks up the current state and then calls the `random` function. This function returns two values: the random value and the new state. Then you just `put` the new state and wrap the resulting value.

`runRand` lets you unwrap a "random" value given a seed. `evalState` lets you execute a stateful computation (that is, a value of type `State s a` or, in this case, `Rand a`) given an initial state and then just discards the final state, only giving you the result. So this lets you run a `Rand a` with a given seed and only returns the resulting value. The value can just have type `a`, rather than `Rand a` because it will always give you the same result for the same seed.

`runRandomIO` just does the same thing except gets the seed based off some global state in IO.

`getRandoms` just gets you a list of `Rand a` values by calling `getRandom` for every element of the `[1..n]` list (ignoring the actual number).